# How do I do an "or" statement with the jQuery :not() function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So, I'm trying to figure out if this is possible or not. I have a `.find(':input:not(button)')` function in my code and I'm trying to exclude additional things besides the `button`. So I'm looking for a way to do this: `.find(:input:not(button || otherthing)')`. Is this possible? I know that syntax isn't correct as it's not working, but I'm hoping that some of you know how to do this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the function instead of the filter, for example:

```
$(element).find('input').not('button').not('otherthing');
```

You can also do this which is much simpler:

```
    $(element).find('input:not(button, otherthing)');
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
:not(button):not(otherthing)
```

will definitely work.  jQuery *may* also accept this syntax, but don't hold me to it:

```
:not(button,otherthing)
```

Comment: Yes, jQuery accepts this syntax, but only jQuery for now. The CSS4-enhanced `:not()` pseudo-class is proposed to accept a list of simple/compound selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a little boolean algebra shall we?

```
~(A OR B) = ~A AND ~B
```

So this translates to

```
.find('input:not(button)').filter('input:not(otherthing)')
```

Comment: your 2nd find should be a `.filter`, otherwise you will ___always___ end up with an empty set

Comment: @RobertPitt: How does it not? He wants to match things that is `NOT(button OR otherthing)`. That's the same as matching things that are `NOT(button) AND NOT(otherthing)`.